# (NSFW) Which one is correct "What a hell" or "What the hell" / "What a fu_k" or "What the fu_k"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-meaning, difference, expressions

We have "**[what the fu_k!](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fuck_2)**" & "**[what the hell!](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hell?q=hell)**" in the dictionary.

But do people say "**What a hell!**" or "**What a fu_k!**"?

Are there any differences between "**What the hell is that?**" and "**What a hell is that?**" or "**What the fu_k is that?**" and "**What a fu_k is that?**"

Comment: It is generally a good idea to censor the F words and other related things. See this meta post for interesting insights: [How I should go about asking a question about coarse language?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5100/i-am-not-sure-how-i-should-go-about-asking-a-question-about-coarse-language). I added NSFW (Not Safe For Work) at the start of your title. It would be awkward if someone opens this at work and their boss sees them reading this.

Answer (score 1):

As an interjection, “what a hell” and “what a f__k” are not usual in English to my knowledge. It is always “the”.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any differences between .... ?

Short answer: Yes.

In my answer, I am replacing "fu_k" with "fudge".

**Definition from Collins:** A "[**fudge**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fuck)" (noun) is *"an undesirable or contemptible person"* (AmE definition no.7 - *Slang*).

---

> The difference between the two forms *"What a ... !"* and *"What the ... ?"* are in their usage and meaning.

But first, note that both *"What the hell?"* and *"What the fudge?"* are emphatic expressions used by people when they are extremely surprised or extremely annoyed/irritated at or by something. See the definition of ["fudge"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fuck) in Collins.

See [Exclamations](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/exclamations) in Cambridge dictionary for the construction *"What a [noun phrase or noun phrase + verb]!"* Em. pointed this out to me in the comments.

Second, to be able to distinguish between the two ('a' and 'the' versions), you would need to have the former in a non-question form (i.e., *'What a hell!'* and not *'What a hell?'*).

---

***"What a hell!"*** can be used to describe certain situations (note the use of exclamation mark as opposed to the question mark - this is in OP's question).  "Hell" is defined as *"an extremely unpleasant or difficult place, situation, or experience"* (Cambridge). Based on that, you can of course say *"What a hell!"* if you are referring to an unpleasant situation: *"What a hell [this place is]!"*

Imagine the situation in BestBuy on Black Friday. One could easily say *"What a hell [this place is]!"* on that occasion to describe the madness, and it would be understood just fine. This expression is used to add more flavor to an observation.

***"What a fudge!"*** can be used similarly. We often say *"What an idiot!"* and *"What a dick!"*. If I hear someone say *"What a fudge!"*, I will interpret it in the same manner as *"What a dick!"*. I have heard *"What a fudge!"* only twice in my life (I remember because I frowned at it and asked my friend what they meant). It is used in the same sense as the other examples. If I had to define it, I would say a "fudge" is a person with less than undesirable qualities.

---

**Don't forget the other use of "fudge" which we like very much.**

A "fudge" is *"a person with whom one engages in sexual intercourse, often, specif., one of specified competence"* (Collins)

In this case, *"What a fudge [she is]!"* is actually describing the partner—bringing attention to their sexual prowess. This essential means *"What a great sexual partner!"*, as Em. says in the comments.

One can also say *"What a fudge [that was]! The best I have ever had!"* after a satisfying session of sexual intercourse. This would be the same as saying *"What great sex!"*

Comment: +1 I was hoping someone could delve into the grammar a bit. Just to clarify for learners, you're using "fudge" as a euphemism for "fuck", which is common. It hadn't occurred to me that "what a fudge **she is**" was also possible. [Here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/exclamations) is a link to an entry regarding _what a [noun]_ from the Cambridge Dictionary that might be helpful. Lastly, in the contrived example I had in mind, _what a fuck!_ roughly meant _what great sex!_, or _what a great sexual partner!_ Just another possibility.

Comment: @Em. Thanks very much for that Cambridge link. I will include that in my answer. And yes, your examples at the end are very common - perhaps more among teenagers?

Comment: Actually, I was thinking that they're not common, at least in the sense that I suggested. Now that I think about it, in the sense of "what a contemptible person", that might be more common. I was thinking the usage I suggested was unusual or rare. Hmm, I'm not sure anymore, haha.

Comment: @Em. Oh, what I mean is the sexual meaning is more common than the contemptible meaning among teens.

Comment: I see. I’m actually not sure. Maybe equally common, but not as common as other more slangy, obscene expressions. Wish I could say for sure.

Answer (score -2):

Slangs and coarse languages are *beyond rules* of any grammar. Also, you cannot take their meaning *literally.* In short, they have the freedom to express themselves without being bothered about *bookish* things.

The [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=what%20a%20fuck) has listed it and has said that it is just another way to say *What the f#$@!.*

So, to answer, both are okay as they are slangs.

Comment: Not sure I trust the Urban Dictionary. “What a hell” or “what a f__k” would not sound right to native speakers.

Comment: I should add that it would not sound right to speakers in Ireland, Britain, or North America, at least.

Comment: What's *not sounding right* in ***slangs***? :P @mat_noshi And, the question does not explicitly ask about *native speakers.* It's slang..spoken worldwide.

Comment: I’ve never heard anyone say “what a hell” or “what a f__k” as an interjection, as slang or otherwise. I think the OP is asking whether these are slang expressions ordinarily used in English. They are not. That is why I would say they would not sound right to most English speakers. It would not sound like commonly-used slang.